# Non blocking code when dealing with Nodejs using database

Tags: node.js

A lot of people when talking about Nodejs talk about the fact that we can write a non blocking code. I have made a website which makes a lot of database queries but there is very rarely an instance where I do not want to await a query before moving forward. For example :

```
let studentID = await pool.quer(`SELECT * FROM Students Where StudentNumber = 'asdas'`)
await (`INSERT INTO StudentHistry(StudentID, Time) Values(${studentID}, NOW())
await (`Upadate Table3 set col2= 'somehting' where StudentID  = ${studentID}`)
```

So most of the situations I have to wait for a result of the previous query to proceed . Is there a way to take advantage of non blocking way of Nodejs?

Also, what about situations where I have to wait for a single query but it takes 2-3 seconds to complete? For example I have an end point like this:

```
router.post("/getInfo",security.isLoggedIn,async (req,res,next)=>{
 try{
    let pool = await connection;

    let info= await pool.query(`Select * FROM LargeQuery`)  //Takes time to complete
    info= info.recordset

    res.send(info)
    }
 catch(err){
   console.trace(err.lineNumber)
   console.log(err)
   next(err)
 }
})
```

If I do not wait for the query the execution is going to jump to `res.send(info)` and send undefined. But at the same time I do not want the entire nodejs application to hang on this line.

Comment: 'await' is non-blocking. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#the_downsides_of_asyncawait

Comment: It doesn't "hang". That's the whole purpose of `async`

Comment: `The await keyword causes the JavaScript runtime to pause your code on this line, not allowing further code to execute in the meantime until the async function call has returned its result `